# Creating a google cloud function that edits a jsonl file based on the filename

Tags: python, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

new to stack overflow so hopefully this isn't a dumb question but I couldn't find the answer elsewhere.

I want to create a google cloud function that runs on a jsonl file when it arrives in a bucket and transforms it, saves it in a new bucket. The files will arrive in a gcs bucket everyday at 3 pm on a schedule, so I am fine if it is just a google cloud function that runs on a schedule if that is easier. The files are also .jsonl.gz files, so I am not sure if I need to do anything with decompressing them before trying to transform them.

A jsonl file is basically a json where each line is a valid json file, like this:

```
{"index": 1, "met": "1043205", "no": "A"}
{"index": 2, "met": "000031043206", "no": "B"}
{"index": 3, "met": "0031043207", "no": "C"}
```

There are about 500,000 lines in each file. The filename would be something like 20181017_nyc_midtown.jsonl.gz. I have a big query table that has each file name and then a given unique id for that file. So for example, the unique id for **20181017_nyc_midtown.jsonl.gz** might be **001924** (random unique id that you would need the table to find). I can make the big query table a json instead to do the lookup for, but then I would have to make sure the json is updated whereas a big query table seems like a better option. 
The big query table looks like this:

```
+-------------------------------+----------+
|           Filename            | UniqueId |
+-------------------------------+----------+
| 20181017_nyc_midtown.jsonl.gz |   001924 |
+-------------------------------+----------+
```

If this is the file 20181017_nyc_midtown.jsonl.gz and the unique id Is 001924 I want to add another column to this jsonl with the unique id. The column would be added to every row, so the output would be.

```
{"index": 1, "met": "1043205", "no": "A", "unique_id":001924}
{"index": 2, "met": "000031043206", "no": "B", "unique_id":001924}
{"index": 3, "met": "0031043207", "no": "C", "unique_id":001924}
```

I would want to save the new jsonl files with the unique id to a different bucket (within the same project). The filename would be the same as the input filename.

in theory, this seems like a pretty simple concept/thing to do, even if I explained it confusing, I was just trying to be specific and follow the posting guidelines.

*[I'm fine with a solution in node or python, I don't know node so python is preferred so I can understand it/edit it need be but either works]*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We do not write code for you. Start with the Google Cloud Storage and Cloud Functions documentation and write your code. When you have a technical challenge in your code, post it here and someone might be able to help you. Search SO for other similar questions. There are lots of example code that has already been posted. Google has numerous documents with sample code.

Comment: @JohnHanley i searched for about 5 hours and tried something and it didn’t work, I would post it but i think it’s useless.

Comment: You are missing the point. Do your own research and then write your own code. Don't post someone else's example.

Comment: @johnhanley I don’t think I’m missing the point, I spent 5 hours trying to do my own research and piece things together. I tried not to post on s/o because it’s intimidating and often people who are experts like you make newcomers like me who can’t figure this out stupid. I spent days doing my own research but am a little lost. Sorry.

Comment: And it’s not like I’m banking on this, I’ve continued to try and how to figure it out but cloud functions are a different syntax and even after watching tutorials I’m a little lost.

Comment: Try Google Qwiklabs. They have a number of labs with detailed step-by-step instructions. If you go to their blog site, they often have free coupons. There is also Google Codelabs. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/  https://www.qwiklabs.com/home?locale=en

Comment: I’ve tried qwiklabs and the coursera course, but still had trouble because mostly everything was in node which made it kore difficult @JohnHanley

Comment: In regards to intimidating, I do understand. It is not my goal to offend - we all started with zero knowledge and I do try to help developers that are just getting started. However, you are asking for someone else to do your work - we don't support that.

Comment: @JohnHanley I apologize, I am really lost and that wasn’t my intention and i can see how that comes off as if i was looking for someone to do the work for me. I can post the code tomorrow that I tried. I just wasn’t even sure about cloud functions.

Comment: I would start simple. Write some code that can list buckets, read and write objects. Then create a hello world cloud function. If you start with one simple task and then another, it will soon come together in your head. There are lots of Python examples, start playing with the simple ones. I can think of many projects where I was head down for days trying to understand the technology before I could write a single line of code.

Comment: @JohnHanley okay thanks, I’ll try again tomorrow with that in mind. I appreciate it  lot.